# Select from same table, within IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am selecting a list from a table, and would like to include the parent's label if an item has a parent, or just `-` if it doesn't.

For this example the table structure is basic :

```
id | label | parent
```

This is he statment I'm trying:

`SELECT id, label, 
    IF (parent > 0, (SELECT id FROM meta WHERE parent = m.id), '-') AS parent 
    FROM meta AS m WHERE type = 'genre'`

I'm getting `[NULL]` for `parent` when the item does have a parent. If I replace the IF statement with `IF (parent > 0, 'Has parent', '-') AS parent` the output is correct.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could with a left join to itself. if the parent is present the parent label will be non-null, otherwise the '-' will be printed.

```
SELECT 
  m.id, 
  m.label, 
  COALESCE(parent.label, '-') AS parent
FROM
  meta AS m LEFT JOIN meta AS parent ON (m.parent = parent.id)
WHERE
  m.type = 'genre'
```

Comment: I have made it little bit complex :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, label, 
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(parent,0) > 0 THEN 
       COALESCE(SELECT id FROM meta 
           WHERE parent = m.id, '-')
    ELSE '-' END AS parent 
FROM meta AS m WHERE type = 'genre'
```

`COALESCE` will check for the `NULL` values and replace that values with 0

Comment: Thanks, this is however still returning `[NULL]` for the label, when parent > 0

Comment: Yes, I have updated query this should also work but left join is far better then this